# How to fix error in Spring boot using objects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a form to catch the user data. However, when I run the application it throws me an error saying that in my html, I have an error in my `input` tag. I made sure to use all the variables in my class but it still doesn't work. Below is the code.

**Home.html:**

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/User-tyler}" th:object="${avsApp}" method="POST">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="filter-search">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myInput" th:field="*{mAppCode}"  placeholder="Search.."/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="myInput" th:field="*{mAcronym}"  placeholder="Search.."/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="myInput" th:field="*{mAppName}"  placeholder="Search.."/>


                    <div class="list-group" id="myList">
                        <div th:each="ary2 : ${ary2}">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action dataObj" th:text="${ary2.mAppName}" th:value="${ary2.mAppCode}"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary eBtn">View</button>  
                    </span>
            </div>
            </form>
```

**AVSApplication Class:**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "avs")
public class AVSApplication {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "appcode")
    private String mAppCode;

    @Column(name = "acro")
    private String mAcronym;

    @Column(name = "appname")
    private String mAppName;


    //Constructor
    public AVSApplication(String mAppCode, String mAcronym, String mAppName) {
        super();
        this.mAppCode = mAppCode;
        this.mAcronym = mAcronym;
        this.mAppName = mAppName;
    }


    //Default Constructor
    public AVSApplication () {

    }


    //Getters
    public String getmAppCode() {
        return mAppCode;
    }

    public String getmAcronym() {
        return mAcronym;
    }
    public String getmAppName() {
        return mAppName;
    }



    //Setters
    public void setmAcronym(String mAcronym) {
        this.mAcronym = mAcronym;
    }

    public void setmAppCode(String mAppCode) {
        this.mAppCode = mAppCode;
    }

    public void setmAppName(String mAppName) {
        this.mAppName = mAppName;
    }




}
```

**Controller:**

```
        @RequestMapping("/User-tyler")
        public String processForm(AVSApplication avsApp) {

            return "tier";
        }
```

**Error:**

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Oct 07 08:58:51 EDT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "home" - line 54, col 59)
```

Comment: For starters you have 3 inputs with the same id. The erorr tells you exactly which line it chokes on, we have no way of knowing which line that is.

Comment: @M.Deinum Its the first ```input``` field. Even when I change the input ```id``` it still shows the same error.

Comment: I guess the error/issue is your field names or better your getter/setters. Use `getMAppCode` or ditch the prefix of `m` totally (not sure what that should add).